# php driver for mongodb doesn't work and gives weird warnings

Tags: php, mongodb, windows-7, xampp

I just installed xampp for Windows 1.8.3 (with PHP 5.5.11) and MongoDB 2.6.3 on my Windows7 64bit system. They both work.

As `phpinfo()` tells me that the Compiler was MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012), the Architecture is x86, and Thread Safety is enabled, I then added the `"php_mongo-1.5.4-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"` (found on https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) to the \xampp\php\ext directory and added the line `"extension=php_mongo-1.5.4-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"` to `php.ini`.

Whenever I now start Apache, I get the (quite unhelpful) Warning "PHP Startup:" twice, and of course the driver doesn't work.
The corresponding entry in the `php_error_log`:`"PHP Warning: PHP Startup: in Unknown on line 0"`.

I've already tried to add the `"\xampp\php"` directory to the PATH environment variable, as suggested in various answers to similar questions, but it didn't help.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Same here: Also running php on the command line with the -i switch will actually work: No error + mongo db is included.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use different build/driver like php_mongo-1.3.6-5.5-vc11.dll

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 OS, XAMPP 1.8.3 PHP 5.5.15 VC11 and MongoDB version 2.6.4 `db.serverStatus()` and encountered the same problem because I used the latest build for the driver which is `php_mongo-1.5.7-5.6-vc11.dll`.

Try this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfH0agF1hIg&list=UU2Jgr4DbVOnX4enxkZWmB2g), it might help you. I commented on this to seek answer and the tutor here answered me right.

And this simple [mongodb installation tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ9ARlZ1VvE)

Hope it helps. Thanks